# Laravel remove public from url on localhost

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On production I have domain `http://xxxx.com`.
In root folder I added `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And when I type in the browser: http://xxxx.com it works.

The same `.htaccess` file I have on my machine. I use XAMPP. And it doesn't work. When I type:

```
http://localhost:8082/myfolder
```

I get 404. When I type:

```
http://localhost:8082/myfolder/public
```

It works.
What is the difference between url in my hosting and on my local machine?

---

For the first answer:
this is a screen, maybe I'm doing something wrong (`.htaccess` is in the root folder), maybe `.htaccess` in the public folder is wrong:
[image: rewrite url htaccess]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```sh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

The problem with your rule is that you're checking this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
```

Which actually checks for URI `/public` from web root however you have your site inside a subfolder locally. Here `RewriteRule !^public/` will check if `public/` is not there at the start after the current directory context, which will work the same in site root as well in a subdirectory.

Similarly for rewriting also make sure you don't use `/` before `public/` to allow it to use a relative path.

Comment: Thanks for response, but now when I type localhost:8082/xxxx/ it change url to localhost:8082/xxxx/public/xxxx/ and I get 404

Comment: Your .htaccess should be placed in root folder or in public ?

Comment: This .htaccess should be placed in root and this won't change URL, it will just rewrite. Test in a new browser or clear browser cache. Try testing with a new URL i.e. `localhost:8082/foo123/`